# cant ping hadoop hostname

Tags: hadoop, ssh, hadoop2

I am trying to configure Hadoop cluster installed using Cent OS 6.x virtual machine,i have configured single node Hadoop cluster first to replicate and form the cluster from that later,but confused on configuration of static ip address for my virtual Hadoop cluster, my ifcfg-eth0 currently look like below,

```
DEVICE=eth0
TYPE=Ethernetle
UUID=892c57f5-17db-486d-b1b9-97efa8799bf0
ONBOOT=yes
NM_CONTROLLED=yes
BOOTPROTO=dhcp
HWADDR=00:0C:29:5C:04:D0
DEFROUTE=yes
PEERDNS=yes
PEERROUTES=yes
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=yes
IPV6INIT=no
NAME="System eth0"
can anyone help me to configure static address for my virtual Hadoop cluster, and also i am not able to ping any other host name other than localhost but can able to ping host address,anyone please help me to resolve this ping and static address issues.
```

Comment: Please [don't just repost the same thing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39843800/cant-ping-hostname-from-centos-virtual-machine) when you don't get an answer; provide more details instead.

Answer (score 1):

A bridge network will help.  In virtualbox select machine, settings>network

Also following is an example of the file you are editing.

/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0

```
DEVICE=eth0
ONBOOT=yes
PROTO=static
IPADDR=10.0.1.200
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
```

There are other requirements. Attached link might help

http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2014/01/how-to-create-a-simple-hadoop-cluster-with-virtualbox/

For internet access files listed below needs to be modified.

```
/etc/resolv.conf

#Generated by NetworkManager
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

Also the file which you modified for static IP /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0, need following additions

```
DNS1=8.8.8.8
DNS2=8.8.4.4
ONBOOT=yes
```

Comment: hi thanks for your reply ,i configured static network like u said ,now hosts in cluster are able to ping each other ,but internet connectivity is not there and not able to ping google.com also....can you tell me how to enable network connectivity without using NetworkManager service...

Comment: Updated answer for internet access requirement

Comment: Hi sagar thanks for your reply ,i modified the resolv.conf file like you said but still not able to ping google and internet not working,i have disabled networkmanager service and started network service only and kept nmcontrolled=no in /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0 file...is it correct?

Comment: please perform "service network restart" check out https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7nXDCoaS2iY  it shows nmcontrolled=yes, I did not even use that parameter though.